# Using cjson in embedded Lua in C++

Tags: c++, lua

I have a C++ program that creates a lua_State and run custom Lua script.  If I would like to have the lua_State pre-load [cjson](http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html) instead of requiring calling "require" in the Lua code, can I know whether it is possible and how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use [`luaL_requiref`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_requiref) for that. Use [this](https://github.com/mpx/lua-cjson/blob/7eb09593cbddfa682f81f198734ce508b519fe00/lua_cjson.c#L1410) or [this](https://github.com/mpx/lua-cjson/blob/7eb09593cbddfa682f81f198734ce508b519fe00/lua_cjson.c#L1424) function as argument. You'll need to link the cjson code to your executable, and the compiler would probably appreciate a function declaration for the `luaopen_*` functions. If you use Lua 5.1 (which doesn't have `luaL_requiref` yet) you can use or steal from [`Compat-5.3`](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3/blob/abf4ea9645ce3ff0c390a57ab3e3e4f82d9a4035/c-api/compat-5.3.c#L559).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But both functions you mentioned are defined in .c file instead of header file, so does that mean I must modify their code or expose the function in some header file?

Comment: You can create a header file and include it, or just put a declaration `int luaopen_cjson(lua_State*);`  at the start of your own source code.

Answer (score 1):

You could call require once through C++ and make a global variable out of the return value if you don't want to call require in scripts.

For example in C++ do:

```
if (luaL_dostring(L, "cjson = require(\"cjson\")")) // run code
    std::cout << luaL_checkstring (L, -1) << std::endl; // print error
```

and after that you can use `cjson` in your scripts like `cjson.new()` without any require or such calls as it exists as a global variable.

Since require was used by C++ then calling require in lua later on will not run the cjson file again unlike using dofile or similar